# Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 0 ]

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am working with Microsoft SQL CE, Windows Mobile application.

I have one table with column type decimal. If through sql query I insert in this column numbers from 1 - 9 everything is fine.

But if I try to insert number 10 or greater then 10, I get this error:

***Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 0 ]***

```
com.CommandText = "Insert into Table(Col) values (@Col)";
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Col", Globals.dok.Class[i].Co1));
```

Comment: What does your sql statement look like. Are you using parammeterozed SQL?

Comment: com.CommandText = "Insert into Table(Col) values (@Col)";
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Col", Globals.dok.Class[i].Co1));

Comment: Specify the type in the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column in Table is actually nummeric(3,2). Numeric(3,2) is any number between -9.99 and 9.99, with up to 2 digits after the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd post a similar issue I had with this same error message.

I have a SQL CE database with a SMALLDATETIME column.   I was trying to insert DateTime.Now object into the table and I would randomly get this failure error message.

Turns out SMALLDATETIME has an accuracy of 1 minute so any datetime value that has a non-zero 'seconds' component was failing to insert or update.

Maybe this will help someone